# How to use SQL Server Management studio - "Execute Stored Procedure" for User Defined Table Types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to right click a stored procedure in *SQL Server Management Studio 2012* and trying to execute a stored procedure which accepts a single parameter of type `tblType_XXX` which is a [User Defined Table Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). But when I try to pass a single value I get this error

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure uspGetXXXXXXXX, Line 0
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with tblType_XXX
```

How can I specify a parameter of type `tblType_XXX` in the *SQL Server Management Studio* -> *Execute Stored Procedure* from the UI?

`tblType_XXX` only contains one column of type `int`

Comment: Hi Rwiti, Did you find the solution for this problem? I am on the same boat. Please share your solution if you have it.

Comment: You can't do it from the SSMS but the solution provided by @Serg is how it should be done.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to declare table variable, insert data into it if needed, call your stored procedure not using `@parameter = 1` format:

```tsql
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @tblParameter tblType_XXX

INSERT INTO @tblParameter VALUES (1)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[uspGetXXXXXXXX]
        @tblParameter
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this. But my question was, if I can use the Management Studio to do this instead of writing the script.

Comment: SSMS makes script template for you and you can adjust it adding declaration line and commenting/deleting parameter names. As I usually adjust autogenerated scripts I answered this way. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: ok .. although I know this .. but since I have got no other answer .. +1

Comment: To be honest I should change my answer. As for now I think that SSMS can't generate anything but `=` but I have no solid proof. And `=` is suitable only for assigning another table variable which should be declared somewhere above procedure execution.